# EntityValidationErrors trying to insert m2m using code first entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have the standard AspNetUsers table and a team table.

They link to a m2m table called UserTeam
I am adding this property to my models to create this m2m link.

ApplicationUser

```
public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

Team

```
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> TeamMembers { get; set; }
```

And finally this code to setup the m2m correctly.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
        .HasMany(c => c.TeamMembers).WithMany(i => i.Teams)
        .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("TeamId")
            .MapRightKey("TeamMemberId")
            .ToTable("UserTeam"));
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is to add my users (who have already been inserted) to the new Team  object like this:

```
        // ... creation of user objects
        // add the members to the team m2m table
        newTeam.TeamMembers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
        newTeam.TeamMembers.Add(user1);
        newTeam.TeamMembers.Add(user2);
```

Then finally I try to add the team object to my context:

```
    using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        ctx.Teams.Add(newTeam);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return newTeam.Id;
    }
```

I keep getting EntityValidationErrors errors on the `ctx.SaveChanges();` line.

My question is then what is not correct with my work? 
Is it my m2m setup or is it the way I am trying to create my team object?

Comment: What do the errors say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was creating my users using my own UserManger class which defines it's own Context.

Then when I create the team object I am instantiating a new context but brings the user objects and trying to add them to the new context. This is the problem.

My work around for now is that I create my users using my UserManager but then with the newly Instantiated context, go and find them out the DB and then add them to the Team object.

Like this:

```
        success = idManager.CreateUser(newUser, "xxxxxx");
        success = idManager.CreateUser(newUser2, "xxxxxx");

        success = idManager.AddUserToRole(newUser.Id, role);
        success = idManager.AddUserToRole(newUser2.Id, role);

        //create the team
        Team myTeam = new Team()
        {
            Name = "m2m team",
            TeamMembers = new List<ApplicationUser>()
        };

        var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // must go get the users using the new context here
        //
        var users = from u in ctx.Users
                    where u.UserName == user.UserName ||
                    u.UserName == user2.UserName
                    select u;
        ctx.Teams.Add(myTeam);
        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            myTeam.TeamMembers.Add(u);
        };
        ctx.SaveChanges();
```